# not able to display the image in java fx using fxml in osx

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I am trying to load an image in java fx using Image view in my fxml file.
the image path is like this :-
project/images/imagename

my fxml file path is like thi :-
project\src\ch\app\Main

my fxml file code for image is:-

```
<ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="18.0" fitWidth="61.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <image>
                              <Image url="@../../../../images/info_512pxGREY.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
```

the same thing works for windows, I am able to see the image there.
In OS X, when I am opening the file in screen builder the image is displayed correctly there but when I launch my app I can't see image there.

Comment: It's a issue of the file being found in the classpath or not. That resource should probably be included in the jar (as well as referenced with a correct path; I guess you don't have `src` as path part in your jar...). You can list the files in a jar using `jar tf` BTW to check, if the image is in the jar and if the paths of image/fxml are what you think they are...

Comment: That resource should probably be included in the jar (as well as referenced with a correct path; I guess you don't have src as path part in your jar...).  can you explain what does this means??      the image file location is same for win and os x and path given is also same but it's works on win but not on mac. as I mentioned in mac I am able to see the image in screen builder and if I make any changes to file path the image is not displayed in screenbuilder also.

Comment: The `project` and `src` folders are not part of the classpath, so they cannot be guaranteed to be available at runtime. The path you provided takes you "out of the classpath", i.e. something like `../..` (or perhaps `../../..` if `Main` is a folder) refers to the root of the classpath, and from there you try to go up at least one more level. In your development environment, where you are running with the classes on the file system, this might just happen to work, but when you bundle your application as a jar and move it somewhere else, it won't work. You need to fix the path.

Comment: thanks for the information, so how can I include my file to jar ?? actually I am creating a exe and .app file from the code so how to include it there ?